# Data Load While Page Scrolling (infinite scroll) with jQuery PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, jquery

I have infinite scroll and on top of this I have ( list of categories  ) so when one of these buttons clicked the infinite scroll updated and new information loaded by ajax, after the data loaded the infinite scroll stop working

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Infinite Ajax Scroll configuration
    jQuery.ias({
        container : '#events', // main container where data goes to append
        item: '.items', // single items
        pagination: '.event-nav', // page navigation
        next: '.event-nav a', // next page selector
        loader: '', // loading gif
        triggerPageThreshold: 5 // show load more if scroll more than this
    });
});
//Set up click filterBy event
$(document).on('click', '.filterBy' ,function (event) {
    $( ".filterBy" ).removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var url = '/rest/ajax/filter.json';
    var divId = "event-category";
    //Process button click event
    loadAjax(this.id,url,divId);
});


//Set up click filterType event
$(document).on('click', '.filterType' ,function (event) {
    $( ".filterType" ).removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var url = '/rest/ajax/filterType.json';
    var divId = "events";
    //Process button click event
    loadAjax(this.id,url,divId);

});



// JavaScript Document
function loadAjax(val,urlReq,divId)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST', // type of request either Get or Post
        url: urlReq,// Url of the page where to post data and receive response
        data: 'data='+val, // data to be post
        beforeSend: function( xhr )
        {
            $( "#"+divId ).show();
            $('html,body').animate({

                scrollTop: $("#"+divId).offset().top
            }, 1500);
            $("#"+divId).html('loading.........');
        },
        success: function(data)
        {
            $("#"+divId).html(data);
        } //function to be called on successful reply from server
    });


}
```

Comment: Does it emit any errors in the console?

Comment: no, there is no error in console

Comment: could you provide a link to your site or a jsfiddle with your code?

Comment: yes bro this is a live sample http://itweblancer.com/scroll2/